# How to access list names through lapply for a function

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have the following named list:

```
all_gene_list <- list(`1` = c(
  "0610005C13Rik", "0610007N19Rik", "0610007P14Rik",
  "0610008F07Rik", "0610009B14Rik"
), `2` = c(
  "0610009B22Rik", "0610009D07Rik",
  "0610009E02Rik", "0610009L18Rik", "0610009O20Rik"
), `3` = c(
  "0610010F05Rik",
  "0610010K14Rik", "0610011F06Rik", "0610012D04Rik", "0610012H03Rik"
))
```

And I have a function that tries to capture the name of each list:

```
make_rds <- function (glist = NULL) {
  x <- names(glist)
  cat("List id is:", x)

}

list_out <- lapply(all_genes_list, make_rds)
```

I expect it to print:

```
List id is: 1
List id is: 2
List id is: 3
```

But it doesn't. What's the right way to do it?

Comment: why not pass `names` instead? `make_rds <- function (glist = NULL) {
  cat("List id is:", glist, "\n")
}` and then do `lapply(names(all_gene_list), make_rds)` Or directly `paste0("List id is:", names(all_gene_list))`

Comment: @RonakShah I also want to access the content of that list. `"0610010F05Rik, etc.` So both the `name` and the content of the list.

Answer (score 3):

What would be wrong with just using apply over the vector of list names:

```
list_out <- lapply(names(all_genes_list), function(x) cat("List id is:", x))
```

Of course, this assumes that you really want a list output from a vector of names input.  I would probably use `sapply` here instead of `lapply`.

**Edit:**

If you want a list with the same original content but the new names, then try:

```
all_genes_list_new = duplicate(all_genes_list)
names(all_genes_list_new) <- paste("List id is:", names(all_genes_list))
```

Comment: I also want to access the content of that list. `"0610010F05Rik"`, etc..`. So both the `name` and the content of the list.

Comment: you can do that with `all_genes_list[[x]]` in the function definition.

Comment: Then it sounds like maybe you want to copy your original list and then use the names you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

In cases when you want to access names as well as contents of the list we can use `Map`/`mapply` instead. We can write a function

```
make_rds <- function (data, glist = NULL) {
   paste("List id is:", glist)
}
```

So we have `data` in `make_rds` function to access the content and `glist` to access name.

```
Map(make_rds, all_gene_list, names(all_gene_list))

#$`1`
#[1] "List id is: 1"

#$`2`
#[1] "List id is: 2"

#$`3`
#[1] "List id is: 3"
```

---

If you are into `tidyverse`, we can use `map2` similarly

```
purrr::map2(all_gene_list, names(all_gene_list), make_rds)
```

Or `imap` where you don't need to pass names explicitly.

```
purrr::imap(all_gene_list, make_rds)
```